# How to save the output of ack to a file?

Tags: shell, ack

I'm trying to redirect the output of ack-grep to a file using the following command:

```
ack-grep "some_regex" > file
```

This command leads to an infinite loop (I guess), and the `file` keeps growing until the system runs out of disk space.

Here's the output of `ack-grep --version`:

```
ack-grep 2.12                              
Running under Perl 5.18.2 at /usr/bin/perl
```

Is there an alternative to using redirection?

Comment: these might help: http://beyondgrep.com/documentation/ack-1.96-man.html and http://beyondgrep.com/documentation/

Comment: This issue is reported on GitHub: https://github.com/petdance/ack2/issues/481

Comment: As a workaround, don't put the file in the current directory: `ack-grep regex > ../file`

Comment: I don't think there is a right answer to this, as it is a known bug. @glennjackman, if you want to make your comment an answer, feel free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply save the output elsewhere `ack-grep "some_regex" > ../file`